# Getting the wrong string from components separatedByString method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, string

I am using the following code to get the title of a string. Everything works up to the line where I get return [s2 objectAtIndex:0]. The problem is that it is just removing the "&" from the string instead of getting the string in front of the "&". For example:

I am trying to get the title from the string "Sweat (David Guetta Remix) - Snoop Dogg & David Guetta". The method would return "Sweat David Guetta" rather than "Sweat". If you can see the problem please point it out, as it will be of much help!

```
- (NSString *)getTitleFromString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *newSongName = [NSString stringWithString:string];
    NSArray *chunks = [newSongName componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    NSString *chunks2s = [chunks objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *chunks2 = [chunks2s componentsSeparatedByString:@"("];
    NSString *s = [chunks2 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *s2 = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    return [s2 objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Edit----- Finalized Code:

```
- (NSString *)getTitleFromString:(NSString *)string {
    NSArray * a = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    NSString *b = [a objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *c = [b componentsSeparatedByString:@"("];
    NSString *d = [c objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *e = [d componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    if ([e count] > 2) {
        return [e objectAtIndex:0];
    } 
    else {
        return d;
    }
    return @"";
}
```

Comment: Did you debug and confirm that the string at the variable named "s" is actually "Sweat & David Guetta"?

Comment: I cannot confirm that. I just NSLogged "s" and it debugs: Sweat (newline) 
& (newline)
 David Guetta

Comment: What are all the elements in s2?

Comment: 1st Element: Sweat. 2nd Element: &. 3rd Element: David Guetta.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.  Running your exact code with input @"Sweat & David Guetta" returns @"Sweat".

Comment: I just tried running the method separately as you did above, and I got the same results as you. I am calling the method like this: `if ([parsingElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
  [songname appendString:[self getTitleFromString:string]];
 }`

Comment: The string variable outputs 4 strings: 1st: Sweat (David Guetta Remix) - Snoop Dogg. 2nd &. 3rd David Guetta.

Comment: I'm confused. So you're saying that the first element IS "Sweat", what's the problem? Do you mean you need to combine then? If so you should call [s2 componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

Comment: Ok so I am calling the method while parsing an XML file. The string in this case actually isn't what I thought it was ("Sweat & David Guetta"), it is "Sweat (David Guetta Remix) - Snoop Dogg & David Guetta".

Comment: You are using NSXML to parse the XML, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the initial starting string `"Sweat (David Guetta Remix) - Snoop Dogg & David Guetta"`:

- `chunks` will be `["Sweat (David Guetta Remix) ", " Snoop Dogg & David Guetta"]` (the string split at the "-")
- `chunks2s` will be `"Sweat (David Guetta Remix) "` (the first element of `chunks`)
- `chunks2` will be `"["Sweat ", "David Guetta Remix) "]"` (that string split at the opening paren)
- `s` will thus be `"Sweat "` (the first element of `chunks2`)

And `s2` will be the same thing as `s`, so the method should be returning the correct thing. If it is not, then one of your assumptions is wrong.

Comment: turns out there was a problem with some other code I was using. The update code has been posted in the question.